# Manual loading&unloading driver in Windows with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, driver

I have a device which is connected to a computer using the USB port through a COM-USB converter, and I use FTDI drivers to emulate a virtual COM port on this USB.

My converter sometimes freezes and the Windows driver too. I cannot open/close the COM, the software cannot communicate through it, and at last - I cannot stop or delete this virtual port from the device manager in Windows. The only solution is to reboot computer.

This software is used in automation, so rebooting is the worst solution we have.

I think, that loading this driver from my program, working through this copy of driver, and unloading it, if it freezes is the only way.

Can you help me, how can I do this? Or maybe another solutions is available?

Answer (score 1):

From what You wrote I think that whole it's driver fault. So loading and unloading won't help because driver doesn't work properly. However this can help You to write a function to load and unload a driver using [.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DLoad.aspx)

Comment: You didn't say that You're working under win7 x64 where You cannot load or unload drivers that way, especially when they are not signed. However the third(using service control manager) method is legal and it should work.

Comment: I also tested on x86 win7. On x86 it sometimes loaded driver, but unload failed at all.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't want to work. So I search for a reason and found a code that I tested on x64 win7 and it works. While working with vs give a reference to System.Management and the rest is almost compile.
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2004-09/6281.html
You have to run this code with administrator rights.