# Programmably selecting a driver using c#

Tags: c#, usb, driver

I have a device that i want to use two drivers on. driver one is the stock device driver and driver two is a custom made driver. Both work on the device. I would like a way to activate driver one or two from my program. I can get a list of drivers but not sure how to activate the one i need. At the moment i have to do it manually from device manager. Any help Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Post that, and any errors, expected behaviors, etc, and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manual loading&unloading driver in Windows with .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091475/manual-loadingunloading-driver-in-windows-with-net)

Comment: The answer's link is dead, but in the comments you can find the source code for a little application that loads / unloads drivers: [Loading and Unloading Drivers in C#](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2004-09/6281.html)

Comment: @MatiCicero the question you linked isn't marked as accepted and the link referenced in the only answer is not even working

Comment: @ibiza I posted the working link, which has the solution to OP's problem

Comment: Will this work using the system32/Driver folder and the name of the .sys. Im not able to activate my driver. hService is always null. I'm running as administrator.